# Google Protocol Buffers not reading properly

Tags: java, ubuntu, protocol-buffers

I am just setting up a new Java project which will (maybe, not so sure now) make use of Google Protocol Buffers. I am new to this API, so I started with a very basic test. A test whose outcome, to be honest, really disappointed me. Why isn't this very straight-forward code working?

```
var output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Message.Echo.newBuilder().setMsg("MSG1?").build().writeTo(output);
System.out.println("output.length " + output.toByteArray().length);
Message.Echo.newBuilder().setMsg("MSG2!!").build().writeTo(output);
System.out.println("output.length " + output.toByteArray().length);

var input = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());
System.out.println("input.available " + input.available());
System.out.print(Message.Echo.parseFrom(input));
System.out.println("input.available " + input.available());
System.out.print(Message.Echo.parseFrom(input));
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
output.length 7
output.length 15
input.available 15
msg: "MSG2!!"
input.available 0
```

It entirely misses the first messages, or rather it seems to "overwrite" it in some way since all the 15 bytes get read. Plus it fails to block on the second call considering there are no further bytes to read.

However, changing the two reading lines into:

```
System.out.print(Message.Echo.parseFrom(input.readNBytes(7)));
System.out.print(Message.Echo.parseFrom(input.readNBytes(15-7)));
```

correctly prints the two messages. I am running Kubuntu 18.04 with JDK 11. Am I missing something really important (not mentioned in the official tutorial) or is this a bug?

This is the .proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package ...;

option java_package = "...";
option java_outer_classname = "Message";

message Echo {
    string msg = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that in order to write/read multiple message using the same set of streams requires using **writeDelimitedTo** and **parseDelimitedFrom** instead, because *parseFrom* reads until reaching reaches EOF.

It seems that the preferred behaviour is to use a new Socket for each message. It sounds a bit odd to me, but I am sure there are good reason behind this. It should be better explained in the official tutorial though.